# Merging similar variables that come from overlapping time periods

Tags: proportion

Apologies for the very confusing title.

For example, in my dataset, I have the list of people who ate an apple from january to march 2022 and also, from the same list, i know who ate a banana from january to june 2022

To create an indicator that is "proportion of people who ate a banana AND an apple," must I only select the respondents who ate the fruits during the same time window (in this case january-march 2022)? or can I calculate this proportion using my entire dataset even if the time window to eat an apple and a banana are different? Does it matter?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: How could you even carry out such a calculation "using my entire dataset" when you don't have the necessary data for most of it?

Comment: sorry by "using my entire dataset" i just meant deriving a proportion of people who ate an apple and a banana (ignoring the fact that for the banana, the people had 3 more months to eat it than apples) does it even make statistical sense? are you saying i should just restrict to the jan to march 22 period?

Comment: I'm just trying to help visitors understand what you're asking.  I still can't tell what your proposed procedure would be, so chances are other visitors will be puzzled or might have differing interpretations.

Comment: i edited my question to add clarity, does it help?